# Expected value of the largest number drawn in n drawings

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, combinatorics

An urn contains balls numbered 1 to N. Let X be the largest number drawn in n drawings when random
sampling with replacement is used. (The event X  k means that each of n numbers drawn is less than
or equal to k.)
Show that when N is large:

$${E[X] {\approx} \frac{n * N}{n+1}}$$

Here is my approach:

$$P(X=k) = P(X \leq k) - P(X \leq k-1) $$

since $$P(X \leq  k) = \frac{k^n}{N^n}$$
and $$P(X \leq  k-1) = \frac{(k-1)^n}{N^n}$$
then $$E(X = k) = \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k*k^n}{N^n} - \sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k*(k-1)^n}{N^n}$$

By using [telescoping sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TelescopingSum.html) and [Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral), I am getting the answer:

$${E[X] {\approx} \frac{N}{n+1}}$$

where I don't have **(n)** term on the numerator.

What is wrong in my approach? Thanks.

**Disclaimer: This is part of my "Probability" HW.**

Comment: You should add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If we call the random draws $U_1, U_2, \ldots, U_n$ then for each $i$ the quantity $U_i / N$ will behave increasingly like a continuous uniform$(0, 1)$ random variable as $N \to \infty$.  What is the distribution of the maximum of $n$ uniform$(0, 1)$ random variables?

Comment: Just as I starting typing ... you beat me to it!